# How to call React component's function from a global context (Coherent UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to React, and I'm trying to develop a UI for use in a game engine using Coherent UI. My UI is built with React, and I'm trying to get messages from Coherent UI into my React app.

Coherent UI provides the ability to send raw javascript script commands to the browser to execute, or to register events, but neither of these has worked for me.

I want Coherent UI to send a simple javascript command `toggleLoadingAnimation();` but I don't know how to create this javascript function in my React UI that will actually call a component's function or change its state.

Here's Coherent UI's info on sending Javascript commands: https://coherent-labs.com/Documentation/cpp/dc/dc7/_binding_cxx.html

How can I format a command or properly register a callback function for a component to be called this way?

Is there any way to just tell a component to call one of its member functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this using Redux and exposing the Store at the window level.

Components subscribe to the store (typically automatically using Redux's `connect()`) and then dispatch messages can be sent and will be picked up by subscribed components.

```
const store = createStore(Reducer, { variants, selectedVarient: 0, loadingVisible: false });
window.store = store;
...
<Provider store={ store }>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

This allows me to issue commands from the console (and similarly Coherent UI can send commands) like so:

`store.dispatch({ type: 'SET_LOADING_VISIBLE', loadingVisible: true });`

Comment: Have you had continued success with this solution? Please consider reading my question here: 
I am using Redux as well

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758834/reactjs-expose-react-component-methods-outside-react-tree

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a React anti-pattern, but you might consider defining a function inside of `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  var that = this;
  window.toggleLoadingAnimation = function () {
    that.whateverComponentMethodYouWant();
  }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.toggleLoadingAnimation = undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change props and then do ReactDOM.render again, react component will keep the state.

Comment: How do I change the props? I essentially need a javascript call that I can run on the Console (at the `document` level) that will trigger component functions..