# reactjs - expose react component methods outside react tree

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

**Question:**

How can I expose a react component's methods to other places?

For example, I want to call React-Router's this.context.router.push(location) from an element outside of React.

Perhaps I could add a React component's method to the window object so it can be called from any generic DOM event listener or even the console?

**Background/Use Case:**

I want to use jQuery DataTables in my React app because it provides many plugins and config which are still unavailable in the React ecosystem.

I started from an existing React datatable component (implementation below).

The original provides nice option to pass a render function which can, for example, render other React components inside the cells. Below, the cells in the 'Product Name' column are rendered as React-Router < Link /> components.

```
    const data =  [
        { 
          product_id: '5001', 
          product_price: '$5', 
          product_name: 'Apple'
         },
         ...
      ];

    const renderUrl =
      (val, row) => {
        return (<Link to={`/product/${row.product_id}`}>{row.product_name}</Link>);
      };

    const columns = [
        { title: 'Product Name', prop: 'product_id', render: renderUrl },
        { title: 'Price', prop: 'product_price' },
      ];

    <DataTable
      className="datatable-container"
      columns={columns}
      initialData={data}
    />
```

What I've done to modify the existing component involves hiding the table from React's DOM diffing algorithm, since it would otherwise break when jQuery DataTables modifies the DOM.

1. Move the component's *render()* code into a custom method *getDtMarkup()* on the class (outside of the react lifecycle).
2. *render()* now outputs an empty div with a *ref* and *id*

   ```
     render() {
       return (
         <div>
           <div ref="dtContainer" id="dtContainer"></div>
         </div>
       );
     }
   ```
3. componentDidMount uses ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup to turn a React component into plain, non-react markup and appends this to the #dtContainer div from render(). Finally jQuery DataTables initializes the rendered table html as a fancy 'jQuery DataTable'.

   ```
   componentDidMount() {

     let table = this.getDTMarkup();
     let dtContainer = this.refs.dtContainer;
     let renderedTable = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(table, dtContainer);

     $('#dtContainer').append(renderedTable);

     let jqueryTable = $('#dt'); // hard coded in getDTMarkup() for now

     // Turn html table into a jQuery DataTable with desired config options
     jqueryTable.DataTable({
       dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
       buttons: [
         'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
       ],
       "pagingType": 'numbers',
       "bAutoWidth": false,
       "bDestroy": true,
       "fnDrawCallback": function() {
         console.log('datatables fnDrawCallback');
       }
     });
   }
   ```

> src https://github.com/alecperkey/react-jquery-datatables/blob/master/src/Table.js#L89-L111

The limitation that has me asking this question is that I am now unable to use React components such as < Link /> inside of this static, non-React markup. I am using < a href=""> for now, but this will reload the page, which is slower and causes the white flash of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to wire up React components with the "outer application"

You can pass methods as props to your component like:

```
const foo = function(){
  alert(1)
}

class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (      
      <h1 onClick={(e) => this.props.cb()}>Hello {this.props.name}</h1>      
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent cb={foo} name="Joe Schmoe"/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

http://jsbin.com/zujebirusa/1/edit?js,output

Using global methods attached to the window. Keep in mind that's hard to maintain as it will pollute the global namespace.

```
window.foo = function(){
  alert(1)
}

class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (      
      <h1 onClick={(e) => window.foo()}>Hello {this.props.name}</h1>      
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent name="Joe Schmoe"/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

http://jsbin.com/woyokasano/1/edit?js,output

Using ES6 module system in order to keep your codebase tidy with separate scopes

```
//methods.js

export function foo() {
    alert(1)
}

import {foo} from './methods';
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (      
      <h1 onClick={(e) => foo()}>Hello {this.props.name}</h1>      
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent name="Joe Schmoe"/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

Comment: You've shown me how to add a method to a React component. That's not what I'm trying to ask though.


What I'm trying to do is bind a React component's existing method to a global context such as window or to a non-React DOM element.

...so it can be called from a generic DOM event listener or even the console. 

For example, how would I bind the React-Router functionality this.context.router.push to window object, so that my non-React DOM element can use that function?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to expose a method from a react component to the "global" scope or outside the react app.
I don't really know the specifics of your case, but this could work for you. Also, I use hooks, but this should also work with legacy lifecycle methods.

Imagine this is my component. It just renders a number managed by a state.

```js
const MyCount = ({ getMethods }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    getMethods({ setState });
  }, []);
  return <h1>{state}</h1>;
}
```

You see, the `getMethods` is the key prop for this to work. This function will be executed when the component is mounted and will provide the methods I need to expose as an argument. In this case the `setState` method.

Now let's pretend I have a button outside of react that I want to use to trigger that method.

```js
// I want to store the methods in this variable
let globalMethods;

// When rendering the react component I pass the prop `getMethods` 
// that will assign the returned value
React.render(<MyCount getMethods={methods => globalMethods = methods} />, $someEl);

// Now I can use it outside
$("#myButton").click(() => {
  globalMethods.setState(2);
})
```

Hopefully, this helps. Or you don't even need this anymore since its already 3.9 years late.

Comment: It certainly helped me, this is an awesome usage. I needed this to get an oauth response from a pop-up window which is on another domain.